# java.lang.classcastException android.content.pm.ResolveInfo

Tags: android, android-listview

i am trying to Display all installed application and their icons. After clicking on the list item I am displaying related records to that application.

Applications and Icon are displaying properly but when I click the list item I am getting the following error.`java.lang.classcastException android.content.pm.ResolveInfo`

```
final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm
            .queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
        Log.i("taa", ": Installed Applications "
                + rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                        .toString());
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(
            this, R.layout.installedapp, list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.installedapp, parent, false);

            final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadLabel(pm).toString();
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

            final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadIcon(pm);
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                    .setImageDrawable(drawable);

            return convertView;
        }

    };
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);///////---->error
    List<String> app_item = dh.getRecordItem(item);
    // Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationList.this, AppContent.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    if (app_item.get(0).equals("No records")) {
        Log.d("Set", "No Activity happened");
        bundle.putString("list", app_item.toString());
    } else {
        Log.d("Set", "Act happened");
        bundle.putString("list", app_item.toString());
    }
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

I tried to print the value of item in log I got this value `resolverInfo{405437c0 com.android.camera gallaru pickerp=0 o=0 m=0x108000}`
But i wnt to get only camera. so that my code for on click work.
what i should do to to solve this error.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are casting `ResolveInfo` object into `String` object that's why you get exception..

Try this

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
 String item =  info.activityInfo.name;
.
.
.
```

And let me know what happen..

Comment: Now i got cleared from that error But  I am gettin null pointer Exception. 'List<String> app_item = dh.getRecordItem(item);'
at this line. log for item is printing com.android.camera gallary  but I want only camera gallary. I dont want package name I want only application name

Comment: What is dh? I can't see any declared line for dh?

Comment: its my db object I am passing application name to it to fetch related records to it. but item returning package name . so I want application name to pass as parameter to dh.getRecordItem(item) function. so how to get only application name?

Comment: Try with  ri.activityInfo.loadLabel(pm) else you have to parse it from name attribute.